# Simple Whois Question

Tags: whois

If I download whois data from these five servers:

```
ARIN: http://ws.arin.net/whois
RIPE NCC: http://www.ripe.net/whois/
APNIC: http://whois.apnic.net
LACNIC: http://whois.lacnic.net
AfriNIC: http://whois.afrinic.net
```

Would that be all the whois data?

Comment: Belongs on ServerFault, no?

Answer (score 4):

No, it wouldn't. Those are the Regional Internet Registries (RIR's) they handle assignment of IP address space to companies.

To get whois information you would need to query the registrar that the domain is registered at. Although the registrars do "cross pollinate" their whois databases. They will just tell you that the information is not registered with them. Since it's not their domain the data may be stale. For example when I do a whois on my domain at netsol (I'm registered with godaddy) in the results it states:

> The previous information has been obtained either directly from the registrant or a registrar of the domain name other than Network Solutions. Network Solutions, therefore, does not guarantee its accuracy or completeness.

I have to ask why you want a comprehensive list of all the whois information. Also you probably won't be able to get it from the registrars without paying a pretty penny if you can get it at all.

Answer (score 1):

No. It would only give you the most superficial information about the domain, including the whois server where the actual record resides.

In case you are asking if you would get some result for all domains by combining the nics in the list, that is unlikely to but the answer is much longer.

You can get detailed instructions on how to do complete whois record checks properly here which will also give you more context:

[Domain renewal/expiration date for european domains (whois)](https://serverfault.com/questions/766424/domain-renewal-expiration-date-for-european-domains-whois/812009#812009)

Comment: We're not very keen on link-only answers around here, since the links rot and render the answer useless.  Normally I'd advise you to add a synopsis of the linked article, but in this case I think it doesn't answer the question as asked, so I don't think even that will help this answer.

Comment: Ah, ok thanks a lot. I'm new here so I literally thought reverse i.e. try to avoid duplicate content. I understand and appreciate the feedback.

Comment: I've edited the answer to better address the question. Thanks again.

Comment: https://github.com/whois-server-list/whois-server-list Add this to your answer :)

Comment: @mikkokotila I feel this answer is now pretty much a duplicate of Zypher's top-voted answer, but you've been very courteous and receptive to criticism (for which **many** thanks) so I am removing my downvote.